# can I change the focus between my two JDialog?

Tags: java, swing

So. I have a MainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame from my MainScreen i open a
JDialog

```
Logout logout = new Logout(this,true,utilajx,user1);
 logout.setVisible(true);
```

then from my JDialog I will open an other JDialog and I Want to set the focus to it.:

```
dlg = new DialogVirtualKeyboardReal(mainScreen, false, codArticol);
       dlg.setLocaleL(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

[this is how it looks like, I want to make my keyboard in focus but i can't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIYsF.png)

Comment: in most cases its depends of how you set [owner & modalityType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog-java.awt.Window-java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType-), then there is an issue with focus (in special cases), or you can to use JOptionPane

Comment: for better help sooner post an MCVE / SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: It is possible?

Comment: Seriously guys, why I get -1 give me answers not -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I change the modal parameter to true it works how i want. Thank you for -1.

```
  lg = new DialogVirtualKeyboardReal(mainScreen, true, codArticol);
           dlg.setLocaleL(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

[And here it is what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsOei.png)